# Find shortest prefix to generate original string by overlapping

Tags: ds.algorithms, string-matching, string-search

Given a string $S$, I want to find the prefix string $P$ of shortest length, such that the original string $S$ can be generated by concatenating copies of $P$ (where overlapping is allowed).

For example, if $S = atgatgatatgat$, I want to find $P = atgat$; $P$ is the smallest prefix of $S$ that can be concatenated (in this case three times, starting at indices $\{0,3,8\}$ of $S$, where the first and second copies overlap but the second and third copies do not overlap) to equal $S$.

Obviously, there is an $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ algorithm by checking each prefix of $S$, but a colleague mentioned it might be possible to do it in $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$. I'm thinking of using suffix arrays for different prefixes of $S$ but haven't quite been able to proceed from there.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about "quasiperiodicity".   This is a well-studied topic and a google scholar search will turn up many papers about it.  For example, there is an $O(n (\log n)^2)$ algorithm
[here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439759390159Q) and an $O(n \log n)$ algorithm [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-45123-4_33).

Comment: I just noticed the OP has cross-posted on this site as well after I posted [my answer here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/100756/find-shortest-prefix-to-generate-original-string-by-overlapping/100764#100764). Since OP is only interested in the shortest substring (which coincides with the prefix of $S$ of length equal to the quasiperiodicity) that covers $S$ there exists an $O(n)$ algorithm.